# Why is a question about Duhamel's Theorem ignored?

Tags: discussion

I'm just a bit curious as to why for the second time, a post of mine with a query regarding a Duhamel Convolution Integral has been ignored, without even a cursory comment.

The first [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299017/solution-of-coupled-systems-with-laplace-transformation) from May 2017 is here and merely poses the question as to how the Convolution Theorem could be applied to an integral that didn't appear to be amenable to its application.

The second [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203682/breaking-up-a-convolution-integral) 2 days ago (Apr 26  2019) with the original question but with a *LOT* more detail, and even an answer that I worked out with a request to have it critiqued, didn't seem to elicit any interest.

What gives? Is this just not a topic that is of current interest, or is is so arcane that it's of absolutely no interest to the Math community?

Comment: You might consider adding a more popular tag, if it is possible. As of now the two tags are rare and not many people follow them.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if that's an option.

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes questions don't grab the general interest for one reason or another (I've certainly had a few that did this). There's not always something that can be done about that - it's unfortunate, but there's no guarantee that every question will get attention.

Answer (score 9):

This is practically impossible to answer: I suspect that the answer is "the right person hasn't seen it yet".  Generally, drawing attention to questions on meta is frowned upon as that's not what meta is for -- bounties are a better way to draw attention.

However, I have two suggestions for you:

1. The question is quite long, and while it's nice to have proper context in a question (+1 to you) you could move the actual question up front to the start ("how do I handle the first term on the RHS given I cannot use the Convolution Theorem") to help answerers know *why* they're reading the question.  While in an ideal world we would all read each question carefully and evaluate it fairly and in the same way, that doesn't happen.
2. You could try asking on MathOverflow; the level of this question looks like it wouldn't be out of place there (though I'm no expert in this domain).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will try and modify the question as you suggested.

Comment: Hmmm  I didn't see that as an option. It even has a bounty worth 250 points thans to a very kind and indulgent user, but still no bites.